# How do we check whether element with MinOccurs = 0 returned?

Tags: web-services

I have an xml schema from a third party web service provider.

```
<xsd:element name="Student">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
    <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
    <xs:element name="Gender" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xsd:element>
```

I am going to consume the dataset returns from this web service in my C# code. Since Address has the minOccurs set to 0, it means the web service can either return value for Address or not returning Address. For example:

```
Scenario 1:
<Student>
 <Name>Eddie</Name>
 <Gender>Male</Gender>
</Student>

Scenario 2:
<Student>
 <Name>Alice</Name>
 <Address>White House</Address>
 <Gender>Female</Gender>
</Student>

Scenario 3:
<Student>
 <Name>Jenny</Name>
 <Address></Address>
 <Gender>Female</Gender>
</Student>
```

May I know how do I check, in my C# code whether the web service return Address.

For result set from Scenario 1, I would like to hide the contact Section from my form all together.

For result set from Scenario 2, I would like to display the contact Section on my form, and have the address display.

For result set from Scenario 3, I would like to display the contact Section on my form, but have the Address field in the contact section set to "Address not provided".

May I know could I achieve that?

I know we can check whether the elements hasvalue or isnull. But how do we check whether the result returned by the web service contains the element (Scenario 1)?

Answer (score 0):

After some research and testing done, I think I can have something like this:

```
bool ShowContactFlag = false;
if (Dataset.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("Address"))
{            
   ShowContactFlag = true;
}
else
{
   ShowContactFlag = false;
}
```